# Simple CSS box-model issue with max/min-width/height

Tags: html, css

I'm playing around with the box models on my test webpage.
Everything is working properly, except when I resize my browser.

I am trying to get the title to cut in half and appear underneath the first bit of the title if the browser is resized to cover *about* half of the title.
This, however, is proving a problem.

Here is my code for this specific problem:

```
#header1 {
    color: darkorange;
    width: 500px;
    height: 30px;
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 30px;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 70px; 
}
```

Currently, when I resize my browser, a part of the title disappears behind the edges of the browser.

I'm guessing I misunderstand the working of max/min-height/width.

Do I need to use the **overflow** command here?

```
<h1 id="header1">
    Welcome to Luc's Amazing Website!
</h1>
<br />
```

Tell me if you need more code, I don't know how much is exactly needed.

Comment: Not sure if I understand but you might try removing the `width` and just set `max-width` and `min-width`

Comment: Using `height` and `width` with fixed values overrides `min-height, max-heigth...` etc. They can be used if height is not specified or is set to percentage value. Also add a bit more of your code (HTML) to see what is the main issue.

Comment: @TodorSimeonov @MichaelCoker I removed the `height` and `width` rules.

Now the page displays the title following the `min-width` rule, even when fully sized. I was hoping it would follow the `min-width` rule when the `max-width` rule, wouldn't fit on the page.

Would using percentages bypass this whole issue completely?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to place both parts in separate boxes. Also `width: 500px;` was not enough to fit the whole title in a single row.

```css
#header1 {
    color: darkorange;
}

#header1 span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header1">
    <span>Welcome to Luc's</span> <span>Amazing Website!</span>
</h1>
<br />
```

Comment: Just like I said on the other comment, though you advised different code, the title now seems confined to two rows, even when the browser is fully opened. I want the title to be one long row of text as long as the browsers width > the title width in one row. If the browser becomes too small I want the title to be on two rows, one above the other.

Comment: @LucasDeijkers  -see updated code. I removed `max-width`. I though you want to limit the title to something less than window's width.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing more of code, though following should be enough to achieve the result you are looking for.

```
#header1 {
    color: darkorange;
    min-height: 30px;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 70px;
}
```

see the example in fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/sh0fevt1/2/

Comment: Hmm, doing this seemed to confine my title to two rows, even when the browser was fully openend.

Comment: As its working in fiddle, probably other layout parts of your HTML code is affecting the grid. It would be easier to figure out if you provide bit more of HTML/ CSS code used.